# Is it possible in gulp throw a variable from html to gulp and load it in a specific folder?

Tags: html, gulp

```
//index.html
@@variable = 'free'


//inde-two.html
@@variable = 'pro'
```

I want to load the index.html in build/free folder
and index-two.html in build/pro folder.

```
//gulp pseudo code
gulp.task('test',function(){
  if(variable == 'free');
    gulp.dest('build/free');
  if(variable == 'pro')
    gulp.dest('build/pro')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read those html files and extract the variables.  Here is some quick code to get you started:

```
var fs = require('fs');

const index1 = 'index.html';
const index2 = 'index-two.html';

gulp.task("move-html", function () {

  var firstFile;
  var secondFile;
  var var1;
  var var2; 
  var re = /@@variable\s*=\s*('.*')/ig;

  firstFile= fs.readFileSync(index1, 'utf8');
  secondFile = fs.readFileSync(index2 'utf8');

  // now firstFile and secondFile are just strings that you can manipulate to get that @@variable.

  var1 = re.exec(firstFile)[1];
  var2 = re.exec(secondFile)[1]; 

  // var1 and var2 should now have your @@variable values from the two html files.

  if (var1 === 'free') {
      gulp.src(['index.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/free'));
  }
  else if (var1 === 'pro')  {
      gulp.src(['index.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/pro'));
  }

  if (var2 === 'free') {
      gulp.src(['index-two.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/free'));
  }
  else if (var2 === 'pro')  {
      gulp.src(['index-two.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/pro'));
  }
});
```

Consider this untested pseudocode.  Parts of it probably won't work as is but it should get you started.